# How to measure Kafka performance with custom application written in java/scala

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using kafka for pub sub and want test performance of entire system with kafka.

Is there any tool readily available in kafka world which can simulate multiple publishers and subscribers to measure latency and throughput considering custom application layer (Domain model message serialization and deserialization)?

Any guidelines around this would be helpful?